# NSSound -(id)soundName:(NSString *)name;

Tags: cocoa, macos, appkit

Does [NSSound soundNamed:@"RandomName"]; cache sounds like [NSImage imagenNamed:@"randomName"]; does? It doesn't mention it in the class reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The soundNamed: method checks the application’s sound cache for an existing sound resource with the specified name. If the specified resource is not currently in the sound cache, NSSound automatically searches for it in several other locations, including your application’s main bundle and any system Library/Sounds directories."

[From the apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html)